# Saving locally stored parseobject to cloud

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to save some data to parse cloud using this code:

```
 ParseObject po=new ParseObject("Gamescore");
  po.put("score",myscore);
  po.saveInBackground();
```

I am successful in saving this object to parse cloud.But I need to store it locally first and then at sometime when user clicks a button, the parse object must update the table in the Parse Cloud and save it self in the cloud.Please don't consider the code as any game scenario,it is just an example,I am using.
I tried to understand parse.com documentation but it is not so much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using local datastore https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore

You can do something like:

```
ParseObject po=new ParseObject("Gamescore");
po.put("score",myscore);
po.pinInBackground(); // now it is saved locally
```

Then later when user press a button

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.get("Gamescore")
.fromLocalDatastore()
.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
      // all Gamescores pinned locally
      for (ParseObject score: objects) {
          // keep in local database till successfully saved online
          score.saveEventually();
      }
}
});
```

Instead of `saveEventually()` you could of course also simply do `saveAllInBackground()` which is more efficient if you have many objects, but then it will timeout at some point if there is no internet connection.

Comment: I tried and enabled the localdatastore in Application but when my application starts it halts for a very long time and then anr is shown and it is due to the
  Parse.enableLocalDatastore(context)
Why?It is not letting me save locally.

Comment: Sorry I don't know. Did you follow the guide and enable the datastore in a subclass of Application? They also have example apps to show how to use the local datastore

Comment: Yes I followed their guide also but not working ok btw I am accepting your answer because your answer to my question is correct.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, thanks .. just sad that it is not working for you. Good luck tracking down the problem.